# Iteration of SQL Server failed logins

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm trying to simulate a bruteforce attack by sending fake credentials to a SQL Server and iterate that many times (~100). I've been trying to use a "for" loop but can't seem to make it work...

```
For ($i=1; $i -le 101; $i++) {
    $cn = New-Object System.Data.QLClient.SQLConnection
    $cn.ConnectionString = "Server=$line;User ID=$USER;Password=$PASS;"
    $cn.Open()
}
```

Any help at all is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify "can't seem to make it work"? What isn't working?

Comment: Just realised that I left off the ; and the " after $PASS. My bad.

Comment: @BobKaufman what isn't working is the iteration. The script only makes one failed connection attempt and then moves on to the next host in the $line variable.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. A few things. First, please edit your question to include this important information rather than just leaving it in an easily overlooked comment. Second, @alas's answer below will get you past one hurdle, but I suspect this is a job for [threading](http://www.get-blog.com/?p=189). And if you're asking about exception handling below, understanding threading is an order of magnitude more complicated. But certainly not unfathomable. And worthwhile to understand.

Comment: @BobKaufman Thanks. I edited the scriptlet to show what I said in my comment. I used what alas proposed below and it is working for me. I'll also read up on threading as well as exception catching. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to catch the exception from the Open() and ignore it. This will work since the connection failure won't break the loop.

Try something like this:

```
For ($i=1; $i -le 101; $i++){
$cn = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection
$cn.ConnectionString = "Server=$line;User ID=$USER;Password=$PASS"
try {
    Write-Output "Try $i on $line" 
    $cn.Open()
    $cn.Close()
    }
catch
    {
    Write-Output $_.Exception.Message
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm fairly new to powershell. Can you explain more about catching the exception or provide an example? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post how you initialise the $line variable?

Comment: ForEach ($line in Get-Content $prod_output | %{ $_.Split(' ')[0]; })

Comment: Edited my answer. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: thanks for that. It works as needed now. I'll be reading up on exception catching now :)

Comment: Great! Don't forget to set it as answered!